# Javascript - Assigning function to variable doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to return object from the function and assign it to smalls variable, the variable smalls is empty as it's length is returned as 0.

```
var smalls = function(){
        var table = $("#box-table-a");
        return table.find("small");
    }, smallContent;
    for(var i = 0; i<smalls.length; i++){
        smallContent = smalls[i].innerHTML;
        smalls[i].parentElement.className += "relative";
        smalls[i].className += "form-absolute-right";
        smalls[i].innerHTML = "<span class='bubble'>" + smallContent + "<span>";
    }
```

While this works and variable smalls has the desired length.

```
    var table = $("#box-table-a");
    var smalls = table.find("small");       //fetch the tr's with <small> tag
    var smallContent;
    for(var i = 0; i<smalls.length; i++){
        smallContent = smalls[i].innerHTML;
        smalls[i].parentElement.className += "relative";
        smalls[i].className += "form-absolute-right";
        smalls[i].innerHTML = "<span class='bubble'>" + smallContent + "<span>";
    }
```

From the knowledge I have on Javascript, one can assign function to a variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Yes, you *do assign* a function to a variable. But why do you need it?

Comment: Paul Butcher - edited the question to be more meaningful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you loop over a function reference and not the result from executing `smalls`.

Yet, as you use jQuery, you can write shorter/simpler code:

```
var smalls = $("#box-table-a").find("small"); // this var really contains the elements
smalls.addClass("form-absolute-right").wrapInner("<span class='bubble' />");
smalls.parent().addClass("relative");
```

This has various advantages:

- the classes are simply added to the list and you don't have to worry about the whitespaces.
- wrapInner does preserve the DOM (with all listeners etc) instead of messing with html strings
- the parent() traversing methods uniques the set, so elements with more than one `table-box` do get only one class
- you don't need a loop at all, jQuery methods are executed on every item in the set.

Comment: Bergi - wow. Never knew that I didn't needed a loop for that. Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to execute `smalls` here

```
var smalls = function(){
        var table = $("#box-table-a");
        return table.find("small");
    }, smallContent;
    for(var i = 0; i<smalls.length; i++)
//                   ^smalls is a function pointer

var smalls = function(){
            var table = $("#box-table-a");
            return table.find("small");
        }(), smallContent;
//       ^execute the function
        for(var i = 0; i<smalls.length; i++)
//                       ^smalls is a nodeList
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have to actually execute the function, not only assign it. 
Change your function assignment to a self-executing anonymous function, this should work.

```
var smalls = (function(){
    var table = $("#box-table-a");
    return table.find("small");
})(), smallContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var smalls = function(){
    var table = $("#box-table-a");
    return table.find("small");
}, smallContent;
for(var i = 0; i<smalls().length; i++){
    smallContent = smalls()[i].innerHTML;
    smalls()[i].parentElement.className += "relative";
    smalls()[i].className += "form-absolute-right";
    smalls()[i].innerHTML = "<span class='bubble'>" + smallContent + "<span>";
}
```

Because the return will never has been called without the call of the whole function.

BTW:

```
$('#box-table-a .small')
    .toggleClass('form-absolute-right',true)
    .wrap('<span class="bouble" />')
    .parent()
    .toggleClass('relative',tru);
```

may even better.